# Verifying output of a command not quite working via BASH script

Tags: shell-script, mysql, database

In attempting to verify if a remote database exists or not, I'm seeing mixed behavior with a conditional statement.

Technically the statement is working (it correctly reports if database is found), but on fail (no database found), it's throwing an error that I'm unable to trace for some reason.

```
REMOTE_EXISTS=$(mysql --login-path=$REMOTE_HOST --batch --skip-column-names -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '"$REMOTE_DB"';" | grep "$REMOTE_DB")

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    die "Checking for $REMOTE_DB failed. Please report this error."
elif [[ $REMOTE_EXISTS ]]; then
    vrb "The database '$REMOTE_DB' has been found to exist on '$REMOTE_HOST'. Proceeding."
else
    die "Oops! We couldn't find '$REMOTE_DB' on the '$REMOTE_HOST' server. Are you sure it's there?"
fi
```

Unsure where I'm going wrong. Login details are being passed via stored configurations from `mysql_config_editor`, which leads me to believe it's something fundamentally wrong with how my condition or method of going about this is setup.

Unfortunately, the error is vague and being caught in a trap in my script, so reporting is a bit fuzzy. Also, I've tried the following as well:

`[ "$REMOTE_EXISTS" -eq 0 ]`

`[[ "$REMOTE_EXISTS" ]]`

No better luck.

Help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just to get you correctly: if the database is NOT found it neither goes to the first, nor the last option in your `if`-query, but rather fails somewhere else?

Comment: What is `vrb`? What is `die`? (This should be Bash, not Perl, right?)

Comment: @Dubu `vrb` and `die` are helper functions from elsewhere in the script. Good question though.

Comment: @Fiximan Confirming this. It seemed to be hitting the `elif`

Comment: @WillAshworth so always on the `elif`? Can you be more specific about the outcomes in each situation? I would suggest replacing the commands in your `if`-query with `echo 1 > test_outcome`, `echo 2 > test_outcome`, and `echo 3 > test_outcome` respectively, to see which case is met in the respective situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try

```
mysql --login-path=$REMOTE_HOST --batch --skip-column-names -e "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '"$REMOTE_DB"';"  > /tmp/remote_db

if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    die "Checking for $REMOTE_DB failed. Please report this error."
elif grep -q "$REMOTE_DB" /tmp/remote_db ; then
    vrb "The database '$REMOTE_DB' has been found to exist on '$REMOTE_HOST'. Proceeding."
else
    die "Oops! We couldn't find '$REMOTE_DB' on the '$REMOTE_HOST' server. Are you sure it's there?"
fi
```

- I am unsure you need to single quote `REMOTE_XX` var.